# Series cash flow

Tags: calculus

[image]

I am simply wondering how we go from row one which to me makes sense and over to row two.

Comment: See "Sum of a Geometric series" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometric_series#Geometric_series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$S=a \left[ 1+k+k^2+\cdots k^{n-1}\right]$$ then $$kS=a \left[ k+k^2+k^3+\cdots k^n\right]$$ so  $$(1-k)S=a\left[ 1-k^n \right]$$ and thus $$S=a\dfrac{ 1-k^n }{1-k}.$$

Comment: Thank you, Could you also show where you go from your final answer to my final answer?

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{1-\frac1{1.05}}=\dfrac{1}{\frac{1.05-1}{1.05}} = \dfrac{1}{\frac{0.05}{1.05}} =\dfrac{1.05}{0.05}$.  Then cancel